# iOS 10.1 Simulator shows "Application May Slow Down Your iPhone"

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

When running an app for the first time from Xamarin Studio on an iOS 10.1 Simulator, I got the following message:

> #### *app name* May Slow Down Your iPhone
>
> The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility.

[image]

The app runs normally, and the message does not appear when I run it for the second time. How can I get rid of this message?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turned out that the app was only built for the i386 architecture and not for the newer x86_64 one. After changing this in the build settings (to "i386 & x86_64", though I suppose "x86_64" would help as well) it didn't occur anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Ref: https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-0-w-xcode8-1-support/

#### Remaining higher visibility known issues related to Xcode 8.1

> [Xamarin Studio] – 45861 – “May Slow Down Your iPhone … The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility.” because of default “i386” supported architecture setting in the iPhoneSimulator configuration on new projects
>
> Fix: Change Project options > iOS Build > Supported architectures to x86_64 (instead of the default i386) for the iPhoneSimulator configuration.

Answer (score 6):

## Why This Warning Appears

Apple added this warning in iOS 10.1. [This article succinctly defines the warning](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/ios-10-1-adds-app-may-slow-down-your-iphone-warning-for-32-bit-apps-1524181):

> "In a bid to push developers to update their apps to 64-bit frameworks, Apple has introduced a new warning message with iOS 10.1. The message reads: “[App Name] may slow down your iPhone”, with a slug, “The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility.” This message only appears if you're running a 32-bit app.
>
> This won’t affect a vast majority of iOS users as Apple stopped accepting updates to 32-bit apps in June 2015."

**Update**: Before [Cycle 8 Service Release 2](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-2/), the default Build Architecture for the iOS Simulator Build Configuration did not include the 64-bit architecture.

## How To Resolve/Prevent This Warning

For Xamarin apps that were created before C8SR2, you can prevent this error message by manually changing the iOS Build Architecture.

#### Build Architecture Causing Warning

This iOS Build Architecture *does not* include the 64-bit Architecture
[image]

#### Build Architecture Resolving/Preventing Warning

This iOS Build Architecture *does* include the 64-bit Architecture
[image]

## Update: New Xamarin.iOS Apps

In the latest Stable version of Xamarin, [Cycle 8 Service Release 2](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-2/), the default Build Architecture for new Xamarin.iOS apps is x86_64 for iOS Simulator builds.
i.e. When you create a new app (File -> New), the default Build Architecture is x86_64 for iOS Simulator builds.

Answer (score 3):

#### Compiling for x86_64

You need to build your app for the x86_64 architecture, whether you're using Xcode or Xamarin. In particular when building from the command line with `xcodebuild`, set `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO` and be sure not to constrain the target architectures with `-arch i386` because you need to allow the compiler to build for x86_64 too.

#### Verifying your app

To verify that your app is built for x86_64, unzip your IPA file and find the binary. `<filename>` and `<app>` are the names of your IPA and app respectively:

```
unzip <filename>.ipa -d $TMPDIR/app
file $TMPDIR/app/Payload/<app>.app/<app>
```

If you see `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`, your app is built for x86_64. You might also see that your app is a universal binary, which is OK too as long as it contains an x86_64 slice:

```
Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
(for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
(for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
```