# iOS 10.1 warning while launching the application

Tags: ios, xcode

Why application is getting this alert and how to solve this -

"AppName" may slow down your iPhone The developer of this app needs to update it to improve its compatibility.'

I have gone through this link: 
[iOS 10.1 Simulator shows "Application May Slow Down Your iPhone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356855/ios-10-1-simulator-shows-application-may-slow-down-your-iphone) 
 From, the above link i tried to set "BUILD ACTIVE 
ARCHITECTURE = NO", but it did not worked.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message appears because your app builds only for 32 bit architecture.

You need to add the 64 - bit architecture in your project's build settings. Just add **$(ARCHS_STANDARD)** in Architectures field and **arm64** in Valid architectures field.

This is also required for apps uploaded to the App Store. Without 64-bit your app will be rejected.

Comment: Valid architecture in my project is “arm64 armv7 armv7s” I am testing the app in iPhone 7 plus simulator.  My app still shows the warning. Should I remove armv7 and armv7s?