# titanium iOS application sometimes show alert "App May Slow Down Your iPhone.."

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I create some business application on Appcelerator Studio(sdk version:6.1.0.v20161230103702).

It run iOS simulator(iPhone 7(OS 10.2)), 
so sometimes popup "App May Slow Down Your iPhone.." alert.

I wanna prevent this alert.
would appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Comment: For what iOS version are you building the app? I think this is an Apple alert for those apps not yet updated to run on iOS 10

Comment: I think this must be something to do with 64-bit compliance. Check if any external modules are updated or not. (See this link: https://www.macrumors.com/2016/10/06/ios-10-1-32-bit-app-alert/)

Answer (score 0):

This alert is supposedly shown for apps developed for the 32 bit architecture.

read [here](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/ios-10-1-adds-app-may-slow-down-your-iphone-warning-for-32-bit-apps-1524181)

I wonder though how the ti sdk 6.1.0 would get you this issue.

what Xcode are using ?

**Update :**
Where did you get that sdk version ?
For production, use one of the GA titanium sdk versions, the latest one (as of the moment of writing this) is at 6.0.2.GA

To install Ti SDKs use this command

```
appc ti install sdk 6.0.2.GA
```

If you don't have an appcelerator indie account, you can use this node package [tisdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tisdk) to install new titanium sdk GA releases.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597208/ios-10-1-1-popup-saying-application-may-slow-down-your-iphone), [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356855/ios-10-1-simulator-shows-application-may-slow-down-your-iphone),  and [this third one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40462981/ios-10-1-warning-while-launching-the-application). There could be something there that you could adapt to Appcelerator Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the latest SDK with the compatible XCode, but are you using any external modules which may not be 64-bit comptible. Can you remove any additional modules, and see if you are getting the error or not. If not, then you need to recompile the modules with the latest SDK or atleast a minimum of 3.5.0.GA from which the 64-bit support was provided.